# getting an attribute from dictionary object django

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary object namely person.json:

```
   def get_web_parent(self, pk, is_ajax=False):

    try:
        person = models.Person.objects.active.get(pk=pk)
        description = person.json
```

person.json is returning a dictionary like {dict}{'description':'example'}

How do I access description value.

I tried person.json.description but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `person.json.get("description", <<other value if key is missing>>)`
 assuming you get a Dict object.

If `person.json` is a JSON string you might need to use

```
person_dict = json.loads(person.json)
```

and then access it as

`person_dict.get("description", "")`

Comment: Works perfect i tried person.json.get("description") and it is giving me a list of description. Now I just have to access the attribute in list.